# How to use Vue router to change carousel slides?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm a Vue beginner and I have a question:  I have a navbar and I want some links ("Link2" shown below) to route to the same view, but each one with a different value (1,2,3), so that I can then build a carousel that updates according to the selected option.

[image: Navbar and View]

I **don't want a route like `link2/:opt`**, because I can't have a refresh in the page, **I just want to bind the link option to a value in the view file.**

I'm trying to achieve that by using a meta tag in the router, and then in the navbar update that meta tag on each option click. My problem is that I am not being able to read the changes in the meta tag in the view. No matter what option I choose, I always get Link2 - option1.

*router/index.js*

```
{
  path: '/link2',
  name: 'link2',
  component: () => import('@/views/Link2.vue'),
  meta: { slide: '1' },
}
```

*Navbar.vue*:

```
methods: {

    goRoute: function(url, opt) {
        this.$route.meta.slide = opt;

        //value of opt is correct here(1,2,3)
        console.log(this.$route.meta.slide);

        this.$router.push(url).catch((error) => {
          if (error.name != 'NavigationDuplicated') {
            throw error;
           }
    });
}
```

*Link2.vue* - where I want to read the value of each option:

```
<template>
   <h1 class="mt-12">Link2- option{{ slide }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
      name: 'Link2',
      data() {
         return {
           slide: 0,
         };
       },

      watch: {
         '$route.meta.slide': function(newValue) {
              this.slide = newValue;
          },
      },

      created() {
          this.slide = this.$route.meta.slide;
      },
   };
</script>
```

What am i missing? Is there a better solution for this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why does the fact that you can't refresh stop you from using params?

Comment: Is it possible with params? Basically with each option, i want to stay in the route /link2 , but change the slide value in the View. If i enter the route the first time, i would like to be in /link2 with slide=1, and if i am already in the route and click other option, just update the slide value

Comment: Yes, that's what params are for. It's not clear why you don't want to use them, but I'll post an answer showing you how anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use route params despite not needing to refresh:

```js
{
  path: '/link2/:opt',  // param called `opt`
  name: 'link2',
  component: () => import('@/views/Link2.vue'),
}
```

Use a `watch` on the `$route` to determine when to change slide.  It will only trigger once you are already viewing the component and click to change (not the first time you route to the component) which is what you've stated you want.  The first time, the slide will be set to 1 because it's initialized that way in `data`:

```js
data() {
  return {
    slide: 1
  }
},
watch: {
  $route(to, from) {
    this.slide = Number(to.params.opt);
  }
}
```

To go to slide #2, for example, use a `<router-link>` like:

```html
<router-link to="/link2/2">Slide #2</router-link>
```

or programatically:

```js
this.$router.push('/link2/2');
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. I was a bit confused, i thought that using params, on each option click or carousel arrow it would refresh the entire page, but it works just how i wanted. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: but one more thing, how can i change slide value the first time i enter the route? I'm trying with the `created` but is not working for me

Comment: You're welcome. In `created` use: `this.slide = Number(this.$route.params.opt) || 1;`